# $window.outerWidth is different in chrome & mozilla

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbee in angularjs and I came across this angular service component $window. While trying to understand it I have this snippet

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="AppController">
</div>
```

JS

```
var demoFunction =(function(){
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);
app.controller("AppController",['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window){
            alert($window.outerWidth);   
   }]);
}())
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a0xdgs8/2/)

But surprisingly I am seeing different value in Chrome & Mozilla even though when window has same aspect ratio.
[image: Loaded in Chrome]
[image: Mozilla]

Comment: See the additional notes [here](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)

Comment: but 1382 in mozilla is too much! Beside there is no margin or padding or border. Is it not the window width,which I have set to 768 in both the browser.I also tried by consoling $window.

Comment: if I were you just use the javascript `document.width` instead of jQuery

Comment: Actually $window is a service component of angularjs. More about it in this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: It's just a difference in emulators' behaviors. Chrome uses screen width of emulated device and FF uses real window width. It doesn't depend on AngularJS, native window.outerWidth has the same behavior. window.innerWidth works consistent in both browsers.

Comment: BTW, this does not relate to AngularJS - $window is just a wrapper for window object. You will get same results with just 'window'. Edited tags.